# Silent type_convert

Tags: r, readr

Is there a way to use the `type_convert` function from the `readr` package without it telling you what column specification it's using in the console.

From the example in the `?` help documentation:

```
> df <- data.frame(
+     x = as.character(runif(10)),
+     y = as.character(sample(10)),
+     stringsAsFactors = FALSE
+ )
> str(type_convert(df))
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  x = col_double(),
  y = col_integer()
)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: num  0.10262 0.15581 0.00638 0.6815 0.98654 ...
 $ y: int  9 5 8 10 4 6 1 2 3 7
```

I would want the the `Parsed with column specification` part gone so it looks like:

```
> df <- data.frame(
+     x = as.character(runif(10)),
+     y = as.character(sample(10)),
+     stringsAsFactors = FALSE
+ )
> str(type_convert(df))
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: num  0.10262 0.15581 0.00638 0.6815 0.98654 ...
 $ y: int  9 5 8 10 4 6 1 2 3 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `type_convert` call with `suppressMessages`:

```
str(suppressMessages(type_convert(df)))
```

For an in-depth discussion see [read_excel read in messages- Supress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227867/read-excel-read-in-messages-supress)