# read_excel read in messages- Suppress?

Tags: r, r-markdown, readxl

I love using the `readxl` package. However, I've been using it as part of an RMarkdown document and some of the `read_excel()` message when reading in files are useful when doing analysis but not when trying to present the analysis. So the question is, is there any way to suppress the message received (or any warning message for that matter) when using `read_excel`? I'll take an RMarkdown OR read_excel solution.

Here is an illustration of the type of message I'd like to suppress. The appears in my final Rmarkdown document:

```
## Parsed with column specification:
## cols(
##   .default = col_character(),
##   Year = col_integer(),
##   Month = col_integer(),
##   Date = col_date(format = ""),
##   Day = col_integer(),
##   Replicate = col_integer(),
##   Time = col_integer(),
##   Depth = col_double(),
##   DenTotal = col_integer()
## )
## See spec(...) for full column specifications.
```

I haven't been able to find a way to read in an excel file from a url using `read_excel` so I'm not able to make a reproducible example here.

Comment: Maybe `suppressMessages` depending on how the package prints output.

Comment: You can wrap the call in `invisible` or you can set your `knitr` options for `messages` and `warnings` to what you would like.

Comment: `suppressMessage()` worked, `invisible()` did not and nor did `{r chunk1, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}`.

Comment: @lmo if you wanted to put that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Does setting the `message = FALSE` suppress the message?  I'm honestly surprised that `invisible` doesn't handle it.

Comment: Yeah neither worked. I was surprised too.

Comment: Setting `warning = FALSE` as a chunk option will suppress warnings... use `message = FALSE` to suppress messages (or use the hammer of `include = FALSE` to suppress *everything*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the package prints out messages using the `message` function, then the `suppressMessages` should work to prevent the messages from printing. From the help file, `?suppressMessages`,

> evaluates its expression in a context that ignores all ‘simple’ diagnostic messages.